# Enforcing public setter

Tags: c#, serialization

I recently ran into a Serialization error that only only manifested on 1 out of the 3 machines that I tested on.

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'XXX' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

It was easily fixed by removing the 'private' from the following line in my viewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Contact> Recipients { get; private set; }
```

I could put a commment:

```
// get and set must be public to avoid Serialization errors
```

But I'd prefer enforcing that the setter is public via code because comments are often forgotten about when code is re factored. I'd like a compile error if a future developer were to change the setter back to private.

I tried using [DataContract] & [DataMember] attributes in the hope that they would enforce the public setter.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether all properties of a type are readable and writable in the following manner:

`var t = typeof (SomeClass).GetProperties().All(s => s.CanRead && s.CanWrite);`

And then use a `Contract` to check whether your predicate is actually matched. You could also `Debug.Assert` these in tests. I'm fairly certain you can't actually cause compiler errors as a result of someone changing the accessor on the property on the fly, so this would be the closest you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a base class that abstracts the properties or an interface defining them I don't think you can enforce visibility on setters from the syntax itself. And even this approach may be problematic since it forces you to switch the problem on an ancestor to your serializable class: how do you make sure that the ancestor has declared all setters that its inheritors declare?

```
// at first
public interface IHasProperty
{
    string prop1 {get; set;}
}

public class SerializableClass: IHasProperty
{
    public string prop1 {get; set;}
}

// but then you change SerializableClass
public class SerializableClass: IHasProperty
{
    public string prop1 {get; set;}
    public string prop2 {get; private set;} // oops
}
```

You can use some additional tooling to ensure that code follows your constraints (for example with [FxCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx) custom rules). You could also check during tests that all properties (or selected properties) have a public setter. It's even possible to do it at startup but i wouldn't recommend it, this is a situation that should fail as fast as possible, ideally in a test in order to give quick feedback to the dev

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I forgot about tests. I'd like to follow TDD but it's still a work in progress.. Cheers

Comment: @MattFitzmaurice You can directly integrate the code fraom aevitas into a test, this kind of checking really belongs there imo

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can enforce a class to expose a specific member public is through either an interface or class. In your case you could create a simple interface containing the members  you needed public for serialization.

```
public interface IMyClassSerialization
{
 ObservableCollection<Conctact> Recipients {get; set}
}
```

You class could in turn implement this interface, which would make it resistant to refactoring and ensure that your serialization properties would always be available.